# Use of [ANY] in Work Item Query

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-workitem

The `[Any]` value can be defined in a query filter to state that we want all matches for this item.

For example, the filter `Work Item Type = [Any]` will return all work item types.

[image: Query Filter: Work Item Type = Any]

**Question**

Is there any benefit to using filters which match on `[Any]` over simply not including those filters (e.g. were the above example filter omitted, I'd see the same results).

Similarly, is there a "best practice" for this; i.e. some reason to use (or avoid) `[Any]`?

**Documentation** regarding the `[Any]` variable: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/using-queries#query-operators-and-variables

**My assumption** is that new and OOTB queries from MS include these filters to make it easy to find and filter on common properties by having the filters present.  Since MS don't want anything filtered by default though, they set the value to `[Any]` so that whilst the filter line is present, it has no effect on the results until customised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you speculate, you can omit the [Any], it only serves as a starting point for your query. Although I cannot prove it in any way, I also think that they have the filter there as a suggestion for you to leverage.